# Python - for loop which yields scraped data only looping once per page

Tags: python, csv, for-loop, scrapy, enumerate

Why does this scraping code only extract the very first title, author and quote from each page? (resulting in only a three-row csv file)?

I am using the web crawler `scrapy` and loading the data into a csv file. I'm using xpath, and have come across an issue properly loading my data. This is my first time using python, and i'm struggling to properly implement the enumerate/zip functions.

```
import scrapy
class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = 'test'
custom_settings = {
    'FEED_FORMAT': 'csv',
    'FEED_URI': 'test.csv'
}
start_urls = [
    'http://quotes.toscrape.com/', 
    'http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/2/',
    'http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/3/'
]
def parse(self, response):
    titles =  response.xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'col-md-4')]/h2/text()").extract()
    authors = response.xpath("//small[contains(@class, 'author')]/text()").extract()
    quotes = response.xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'quote')]/span[contains(@class, 'text')]/text()").extract()
    for i, (title, author, quote) in enumerate(zip(titles, authors, quotes)):
        yield {'index': i, 'title': title, 'author': author, 'quote': quote}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that `zip` only creates the same number of elements as the minimum list passed as an argument, in this case `titles` only contains `1` element, so it is correct that the for will only iterate once.

If you want that same title for all of the elements, you should only iterate `authors` and `quotes`:

```
title =  response.xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'col-md-4')]/h2/text()").extract_first()
authors = response.xpath("//small[contains(@class, 'author')]/text()").extract()
quotes = response.xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'quote')]/span[contains(@class, 'text')]/text()").extract()
for i, (author, quote) in enumerate(zip(authors, quotes)):
    yield {'index': i, 'title': title, 'author': author, 'quote': quote}
```